# Transpose data in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, linear-regression, transpose

I have a large DataFrame (7 GB csv loaded via pandas.read_csv) with the following structure:

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]: 

ID            Month           Transaction_Amount

1             2014/01         10
1             2014/02         20
1             2014/03         10
1             2014/04         20
1             2014/05         10
1             2014/06         20
1             2014/07         10
1             2014/08         20
1             2014/09         10
1             2014/10         20
1             2014/11         10
1             2014/12         20
2             2014/01         15
2             2014/02         25
2             2014/03         15
2             2014/04         25
...
10000000      2014/11         13
10000000      2014/12         23
```

I would like to do a linear regression for each of the ID's over the 12 months of data.  The ultimate goal is to get the value of the slope for each of the linear regression and associate that number with an ID.  My first thought is that to perform this regression I should create a new DataFrame with the following structure:

```
In [2]: my_new_transposed_df
Out[2]:

ID          01      02      03      04   ...    11      12      

1           10      20      10      20          10      20
2           15      25      15      25   ...    15      25
...
10000000    13      23      13      23   ...    13      23
```

At this point, I would then perform the regression on each line and record the slope:

```
In [1]: my_new_transposed_df['linear_reg_slope'] = my_new_transposed_df.perform_linear_regression(rows=(1:12))
```

However, I am having trouble accomplishing both of these steps, the first being doing the transformation (transposition, I think?) and the second being performing the regression.

Comment: You should use `groupby` to group your data into multiple DataFrames (one for each ID), and then do the regression on each one.  Check out [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html).

Comment: Can you elaborate?  I have used `groupby` in conjunction with `sum()` to sum the data across multiple rows, but not to perform a transposition.

Comment: What I'm saying is you don't want to perform a "transposition".  You just need to group the data and do an operation on each group.  You can do `df.groupby('ID')['Transaction Amount'].apply(myFunction)`, where `myFunction` is some function that takes a Series (the transaction data) and does the regression and returns the slope (or whatever other data you want).  You don't actually need to create that giant transposed DataFrame just to do a regression on each ID separately.

Comment: The 'transposition' you are looking for is really [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html). You would do something like `df.set_index(['ID','Month']).unstack()`. However, as BrenBarn said, if you don't need to create the extra DF it might be better not to.

Comment: I'm looking into using the `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression` module but am unsure on the syntax to use the `LinearRegression` in the `apply` function that BrenBarn suggested.

Comment: Anyone know how to create the `myFunction` that BrenBarn suggested I use above?  Is it possible to use a preexisting linear regression function?